# Хочу добавить свое приложение в Одноклассники

Tags: javascript, odnoklassniki-api

Я разрабатываю веб приложение которое впоследствии хочу добавить в соц сеть Одноклассники через их iframe.

В данный момент логин в мое приложение реализован через OAuth2 Одноклассников.

Этого достаточно для добавления в их соц сеть ? Просто в их документации все время путаются праметры session_key  и в случае OAUTH - access_token. В данный момент логин у меня реализовано через их OAuth2.

Локально что бы залогиниться в мое приложение через Одноклассников необходимо вызвать след урл - https://127.0.0.1:8443/login/ok В этом случае или будет редирект на их логин форму или произойдет автоматический вход в приложение в случае наличия активной сессии пользователя в Одноклассниках.

Такого логина для них достаточно ?

**Обновлено**

В данный момент я подключил это тестовое приложение в iframe Одноклассников. Этот iframe загружает приложение через OAuth2 логин урл для Одноклассников  на моем сайте https://127.0.0.1:8443/login/ok (приложение для теста поднято у меня на локалхосте).

В данный момент при переходе по урл вида http://ok.ru/game/{APP_ID} я вижу в iframe Одноклассников свое приложение с авторизированным пользователем.

Заметил еще одну вещь - если пользователь первый раз заходит на логин урл Одноклассников в моем приложении https://127.0.0.1:8443/login/ok напрямую вбив этот урл в браузере то Одноклассники просят авторизировать(войти) пользователя в это приложение(такой себе дополнительный шаг). Если же пользователь идет первый раз сразу через сайт Одноклассников через урл игры http://ok.ru/game/{APP_ID} то никакого подтверждения ему делать не нужно и я сразу вижу этого пользователя через OAuth2 в своем приложении.

На первый взгляд все работает отлично. Смущает один момент - при загрузке моего приложения в свой IFRAME Одноклассники передают ему кучу параметров как то logged_user_id, sig, session_key, application_key и так далее. Мне же в свою очередь ни один из этих параметров не нужен так как я имею авторизированного пользователя и соответственно его OAuth2 accessToken с которым могу обращаться к API Одноклассников.

Вопрос - мне действительно хватит только этот accessToken и передаваемыми параметрами при загрузке в iframe можно принебречь ? Судя по тому как я описал подключение своего приложения, все ли я сделал правильно ?

**Обновлено**

После еще пару часов ковыряния с АПИ я так понимаю параметры запроса которые Одноклассники передают в урл для iframe всетаки нужны для например JavaScript API.